# ioctl make routes disappear

Tags: linux, networking, ioctl

I have an issue with ioctl (I think).

The software is a debian package which gets installed in the boot process of the machine and is started up right after that. The software sets up networking through the use of /etc/network/interfaces. The IP and netmask are getting written to the interfaces config file, the routes are added via the up command inside the interfaces config file.

```
# CONFIG_MARKER eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.237
netmask 255.255.255.0
up route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.0.126 dev eth0
down route del -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.0.126 dev eth0
up route add default gateway 192.168.0.126 dev eth0
down route del default gateway 192.168.0.126 dev eth0
# CONFIG_MARKER eth0

# CONFIG_MARKER prp1
auto prp1
iface prp1 inet static
address 192.168.20.237
netmask 255.255.255.0
up route add -net 192.168.20.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.20.1 dev prp1
down route del -net 192.168.20.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.20.1 dev prp1
```

After the configuration file has been created, the software uses ifdown and ifup to start up the Interface that was setup. (So each Interface is first set up in interface configt file and then started via ifup, so one interface gets configured and then started up, then the next interface gets configured and started up...)

Now the issue arises when I use a function (command line) that uses ioctl to read interface information, after that call, the routing table will be empty (or rather, the manually [via up command in interface config file] added routes will be gone).

The function only reads data from the opened file descriptor on the socket of the queried interface, no data will be set there and then.

Totally unexpected is the behavior when after the routes where deleted, I manually (from command line) call ifdown and ifup on the interfaces and the call to the function with ioctl (which on boot up would delete the routes configured) will not delete the routes anymore.

Can anyone point me to what could be an issue here? 
(The interface eth0 is a service interface where calls for a website come in for example. The interface prp1 is a virtual interface which wraps 2 real interfaces [eth1 and eth2 unconfigured] over PRP. There is also some SCL setup going on, which inside uses ioctl for interface queries as well. I was assured, that the IEC61850 communication setup is not to blame for the described behavior.)

### EDIT

As per request, the code of the function causing the problem:

```
NetworkInterface::NicParameter NetworkHelper::getNicParameter(
        const std::string& ifaceName) {

    NetworkInterface::NicParameter nicParam;

    nicParam.ifaceName  = ifaceName;
    nicParam.opState    = getOperationalState(ifaceName);
    nicParam.opMode     = getOperationalMode(ifaceName);
    nicParam.linkStatus = getLinkStatus(ifaceName);
    nicParam.speed      = getSpeed(ifaceName);

    // Get the IP address of the current interface.
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    struct ifreq ifr;
    ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;

    // Copy the interface name in the ifreq structure.
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, ifaceName.c_str(), IFNAMSIZ - 1);
    // get the ip address.
    ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);
    nicParam.ipAddress
        = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr);

    // Get the netmask of the current interface.
    ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFNETMASK, &ifr);
    nicParam.netmask
        = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr);

    // Get the gateway address of the current interface.
    ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFDSTADDR, &ifr);
    nicParam.gateway = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr);

    // Get the broadcast address of the current interface.
    ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFBRDADDR, &ifr);
    nicParam.broadcastAddress
            = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr);

    // Get the broadcast address of the current interface.
    struct ifreq req;
    strcpy(req.ifr_name, ifaceName.c_str());
    char macAddress[18]; // 17 characters + null terminator
                         // example: 01:02:03:04:05:06
    if (ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &req) != -1) {
        uint8_t *mac = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(
            req.ifr_ifru.ifru_hwaddr.sa_data);
        sprintf(macAddress, "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X",
                mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
    }
    nicParam.macAddress = std::string(macAddress);

    close(fd);

    // Get the total number of received bytes.
    int returnValue;
    std::string procNetDev = "cat /proc/net/dev | grep " + ifaceName;
    nicParam.receivedPackets.numBytes = OsHelper::executeCommandInt(
        procNetDev + " | awk '{print $2}'", returnValue);

    // Get the total number of received packets.
    // Include the number of faulty and dropped packets.
    nicParam.receivedPackets.numPackets = OsHelper::executeCommandInt(
        procNetDev + " | awk '{print $3}'", returnValue);
    nicParam.receivedPackets.numErrors = OsHelper::executeCommandInt(
        procNetDev + " | awk '{print $4}'", returnValue);
    nicParam.receivedPackets.numDroppedPackets = OsHelper::executeCommandInt(
        procNetDev + " | awk '{print $5}'", returnValue);

    // Get the total number of transmitted bytes.
    nicParam.transmittedPackets.numBytes = OsHelper::executeCommandInt(
        procNetDev + " | awk '{print $10}'", returnValue);

    // Get the total number of transmitted packets.
    // Include the number of faulty and dropped packets.
    nicParam.transmittedPackets.numPackets = OsHelper::executeCommandInt(
        procNetDev + " | awk '{print $11}'", returnValue);
    nicParam.transmittedPackets.numErrors = OsHelper::executeCommandInt(
        procNetDev + " | awk '{print $12}'", returnValue);
    nicParam.transmittedPackets.numDroppedPackets = OsHelper::executeCommandInt(
        procNetDev + " | awk '{print $13}'", returnValue);

    // Check if DHCP is enabled or not.
    returnValue = 0;
    OsHelper::executeCommand("cat /etc/network/interfaces | grep -v '#' | grep "
        + ifaceName + " | grep dhcp", returnValue);
    if (returnValue == 0)
        nicParam.dhcpState = "enabled";
    else
        nicParam.dhcpState = "disabled";

    return nicParam;
}
```

The broadcast is not retrieved correctly, its some other function call really... don't mind that!

Comment: You need to post the code that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found my problem...
it's a somewhat embarrasing mistake.

In the function you will find "ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFBRDADDR, &ifr);" which, when seen in one line without all the other calls around, clearly "Sets" a parameter instead of retrieving it (the broadcast address siocS... instead of siocG...). And setting some things on an interface wiull cause routes to be deleted obviously, since the NIC changed, the routes would be errornous.

Thx for reading.